# Want to make the output human readable

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

Hello, I am trying to run some queries but my output is not right. Could anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
I am trying to find the difference between these two DATETIME values as minutes.

`SELECT TO_CHAR(booking_StartTime - booking_EndTime) AS Diff FROM Booking;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `booking_StartTime` and `booking_EndTime` are DATE fields - when doing arithmetic using DATE values in Oracle the result is a number of DAYS. Thus, to get minutes you have to multiply by the number of minutes in a day, i.e. by 24 * 60, or 1440. Also - you probably want to subtract the start time from the end time, in order to get a positive value as the result.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((booking_EndTime - booking_StartTime) * 1440) AS Diff FROM Booking;
```

should get you what you want.